# DevExpress:How to programmatically remove a column from XtraReport?

Tags: devexpress

I have a Web application with XtraReport report. The report has several columns. 
Depending on a certain condition, in certain situations I do not need one of the columns to exist. What is a best way to programmatically remove it? I need not to ‘make the column invisible’, but remove it. The space that the column occupied before the removal should be distributed evenly between the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

*A proper solution is to temporary remove the unnecessary XRTableCell from the XRTableRow.Cells collection...*

Review the http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q216567 discussion in the DevExpress support center. Hope this helps.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to remove the cell from the row (for example on the report BeforePrint event). You should also wrap it in the suspend-resume layout code for the table itself:

```cs
private void TableReport_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    xrTable1.SuspendLayout();
    xrTableRow1.Cells.Remove(xrTableCell1);
    xrTable1.PerformLayout();
}
```

Comment: How can I apply this code depending on a variable, say, some property of the model?

Answer (score 0):

you can use dispose the cell
  If CEHide.Checked = True Then
XrTableCell2.Dispose()